# postgresql and node with redis still making connection to db pool?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm a bit stuck here and was hoping to get some help.

My node application has a seperate module where I connect to postgres and export the pool as so

```
const {Pool,Client} = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    port:  process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    keepAlive: 0,
    ssl:{ rejectUnauthorized: false,
        sslmode:require},
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000, // 10 seconds
    allowExitOnIdle:true,
    max: 10
});
pool.connect()
    .then(() => console.log('postgress connected'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))

module.exports  =  pool
```

On my route, I have redis cache as middleware, this works as expected and can confirm it is being served up by redis, the logic in the route does not run when the request is cached, however I was doing some load testing to see how everything would handle spikes and noticed I started to get errors from postgres

```
Error: timeout exceeded when trying to connect
```

I also got errors talking about max connections etc.

I have tried to increase the max pool connection but still seem to get this error when running some larger load tests.

My question is, why, would PG be trying to connect if the connection should be shared? Additionally, why is it even trying to connect if the request is cached?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some of your stress test cases are missing the redis cache. You haven't shown any code relevant to that, so what more can be said?

The error you show is not generated by PostgreSQL, it is generated by node's 'pg' module.  You configured it to only allow 10 simultaneous connections. If more than that are requested, they have to line up and wait. And you also configured it to wait only for 10 seconds before bombing out with an error, and that is exactly what you are seeing.

You vaguely allude to other errors, but you would have to share the actual error message with us if you want help.

The system seems to be operating as designed. You did a stress test to see what would happen, and you have seen what happens.